# Create Non Readable Directory in Android

Tags: android

I want to create a directory in device internal storage, which should be hidden for all the user from other apps like file explorer or file manager. Should I use any encryption technique for this?

Comment: what about Shared Preferences ? why you need a Directory?

Comment: I am having a directory containing many sub-folders and files in it, but the requirement is , user should not be able to delete these files using any third party apps like file explorer or file manager. Is there any way to to restrict the user to delete those files or read those files.

Answer (score 2):

If the folder is on internal storage, it will already be hidden from file explorer and file manager apps, unless the user has a rooted phone. If he has a rooted phone, there is no way you can hide the folder from him.